# How can I get tree-like indentation for Flutter code in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How do I make VS Code do scaffolding guides like in the picture below?:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found it mentioned and shown here: [dart and flutter extensions](https://medium.com/flutter-community/must-have-vs-code-extensions-for-working-with-flutter-e31a421b9c68):

> in the settings and enable the `Dart:Preview Flutter Ui Guides` option

Unless you are using the Dart language you are not going to be able to get that same indent guide effect as it requires that specific syntax to parse and enable the feature to work.

Comment: That's right - and I wouldn't expect many to copy it, as the way it works is very hacky (unicode characters over the editor). If there was a better API, maybe others would adopt it. This VS Code issue would appreciate your thumbs ups! :D https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73780

Comment: Done, I like the look and it provides instant feedback.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

enabling these two options like on the pic

Answer (score 6):

on Vscode Click `Code` -> `Preferences` -> `Settings`

and search for `Preview Bazel Workspace Custom Scripts` and `check` it

and search for `Preview Flutter Ui Guides`

and Check `Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides`
and Check `Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides Custom Tracking`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't need the Bazel setting here, that's for something unrelated (to support some specific Bazel workspaces, mostly intended for internal Google users).

Answer (score 4):

Open your VS code workspace and check:

```
Dart: Preview Bazel Workspace Custom Scripts
Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides
Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides Custom Tracking
```

Comment: You don't need the Bazel setting here, that's for something unrelated (to support some specific Bazel workspaces, mostly intended for internal Google users).

Answer (score 4):

run the Dart: Use Recommended Settings command from the VS Code command palette (ctrl + shift + P)and dart recommended setting will be written on your setting.json file.

and open the setting.json add this on top or below the dart settings and restart VsCode

```json
"dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true,
"dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking": true,
```

Answer (score 2):

*This tree like indentation in vscode is **UI Guide** for Flutter.*

### Method 1

1. First of all please check in your *VS code workspace* **Dart Plugin** is enable.
2. Press `Ctrl + ,`
3. In search box Type `Dart:Preview Flutter Ui Guides`
   [image]
4. Turn on both options for  work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go in the settings and enable the `Dart:Preview Flutter Ui Guides` option. That will make it really easy to spot the parent-child relationships in your code, which is particularly useful when you have many nested widgets in your UI files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Search and check this (for new versions)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [the Flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter). (Actually, the following steps might work even if you only install [the Dart extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code), since the following settings are all registered under the Dart extension instead of the Flutter one for some odd reason)
2. Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

   ```json
   "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true
   ```

   The setting's description (at the time of this writing):

   > EXPERIMENTAL: Whether to enable the [Flutter UI Guides preview](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-1/#preview-flutter-ui-guides).

   Quoting from that linked documentation:

   > - The rendered lines may be broken/dashed depending on your editor line height. You can avoid the broken lines by adjusting your editor line height (for example `"editor.lineHeight": 15`). We’re looking for ways to avoid this (and would appreciate s on [this VS Code issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73780)).
   > - There may be a delay between modifying code and the guides updating. You may be able to reduce this delay by enabling `dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking`. Feedback on whether guides work better with or without custom tracking should be posted in [this issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1731).
   > - Enabling UI guides does not automatically turn off Closing Labels, so you may also wish to also disable `dart.closingLabels`.
   > - You’ll need to restart VS Code (or run the **Reload Window** command) after changing the UI Guides settings for them to apply.
3. See also the following related settings to see if you want to adjust them:

   - `dart.flutterUiGuides`: "*The color of the Flutter UI Guidelines shown in the editor.*"
   - `dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking`: "*EXPERIMENTAL: Whether to enable custom tracking of Flutter UI guidelines (to hide some latency of waiting for the next Flutter Outline).*"

Loosely related on the point of doing Flutter development with VS Code: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code.