# When doing Flutter development with VS Code, how can I get code scaffolding guides?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, scaffolding

How can I get the code/components scaffolding guide lines shown in the following screenshot?

[image: Scaffolding guide line in red arrow]

I would like to know what plugins or method/settings to use in order to get this during coding as it will enhance productivity in a large code base.

Comment: Also editor.guides.indentation needs to be true, which it is by default, but you might have accidentally disabled it. Also, I have editor.lineHeight set to 1.4 because it makes the guides touch instead of the little gap normally there.

Comment: if you don't want people to know how you look (using some basic Photoshop) or what lamp you have in your room use the screen capture feature of your computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [the Flutter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter). (Actually, the following steps might work even if you only install [the Dart extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code), since the following settings are all registered under the Dart extension instead of the Flutter one for some odd reason)
2. Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

   ```json
   "dart.previewFlutterUiGuides": true
   ```

   The setting's description (at the time of this writing):

   > EXPERIMENTAL: Whether to enable the [Flutter UI Guides preview](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-1/#preview-flutter-ui-guides).

   And quoting from that linked documentation:

   > - The rendered lines may be broken/dashed depending on your editor line height. You can avoid the broken lines by adjusting your editor line height (for example `"editor.lineHeight": 15`). We’re looking for ways to avoid this (and would appreciate s on [this VS Code issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73780)).
   > - There may be a delay between modifying code and the guides updating. You may be able to reduce this delay by enabling `dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking`. Feedback on whether guides work better with or without custom tracking should be posted in [this issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1731).
   > - Enabling UI guides does not automatically turn off Closing Labels, so you may also wish to also disable `dart.closingLabels`.
   > - You’ll need to restart VS Code (or run the **Reload Window** command) after changing the UI Guides settings for them to apply.
3. See also the following related settings to see if you want to adjust them:

   - `dart.flutterUiGuides`: "*The color of the Flutter UI Guidelines shown in the editor.*"
   - `dart.previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTracking`: "*EXPERIMENTAL: Whether to enable custom tracking of Flutter UI guidelines (to hide some latency of waiting for the next Flutter Outline).*"
4. Profit.

Loosely related on the point of doing Flutter development with VS Code: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code.

Comment: More ways of getting the same done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58032083/how-can-i-get-tree-like-indentation-for-flutter-code-in-vs-code. But this answer by the @user help my issue resolved.